# hyperlink should come in multiline code not working

Tags: asp.net

i use this code .. but when the hyperlinks are longer then field size the gridview expands verticaly. i want the link below as like a paragraph . give me a solution

```
      <asp:gridview id="titlesGrid" runat="server"    

           datasourceid="titles"

         width=90% cellpadding=5 font-size="8pt"

             autogeneratecolumns=false

          headerstyle-backcolor="maroon"

           headerstyle-forecolor="khaki"

          headerstyle-font-bold

          rowstyle-verticalalign="top">


   <columns>


       <asp:hyperlinkfield headertext="Title"

          datatextfield="title"

         datanavigateurlformatstring="title_details.aspx?titleid={0}"

          datanavigateurlfields="title_id" />


       <asp:boundfield headertext="Title ID"

       datafield="title_id" />


         <asp:boundfield headertext="Category"

            datafield="type" />


             <asp:boundfield headertext="Pub ID"

              datafield="pub_id" />


              <asp:boundfield headertext="Price"

                  datafield="price"

                  htmlencode=false  

                  dataformatstring="{0:n2}"  

              itemstyle-horizontalalign="right" />   

                      </columns>    



                      </asp:gridview>
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using `<ItemStyle Wrap="True" />` for `<asp:hyperlinkfield />` ?

Comment: still not working .. can u tell me where i have to put <ItemStyle Wrap="True" />